# Glorifying others as a bad act

Tags: scripture, mahabharata

Consider the following statements of Sisupala from Mahbharatha.

> O king, what can be done by me when (it seemeth) thou hast not heard
> anything before from virtuous old men giving lessons in morality? Hast
> thou never heard, O Bhishma, that reproach and **glorification**, both of
> self and **others**, are not practices of those that are respectable?
>
> [[Section 43, Sisupala-badha Parva, Sabha Parva, The Mahabharata]](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m02/m02043.htm)

From the statements of Sisupala, it can be understood that glorifying others is a unrespectable act.

I am asking this question because Sisupala's statements cannot be treated as facts. Sisupala is saying that it has been told by virtuous old men. So, there are chances that scriptures may contain it.

Do any scripture (exactly) tells that **glorifying others is a bad act among humans**?

This question does not ask about glorifying gods or others divine beings.

Comment: People can glorify their parents, guru, elders, who by theological standards are not "divine" per say (although, they maybe considered divine for their kin & kith, but still not the whole world). So, glorifying others in that sense is not a sin. And that's not bad.